# How to set Sun Java JDK as default on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit

Tags: ubuntu, installation, java

I have a 64 bit Ubuntu installation with OpenJDK as default Java version.

> jeffrey@jeffrey-Satellite-M645:~$ java -version java version
>   "1.6.0_27" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.5)
>   (6b27-1.12.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build
>   20.0-b12, mixed mode) jeffrey@jeffrey-Satellite-M645:~$

I would like to change this to Oracle version:

```
jdk-6u43-linux-x64
```

I have downloaded the `jdk-6u43-linux-x64.bin` file and ran

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/share/java/jdk-6u43-linux-x64.bin
```

followed by

```
sudo /usr/share/java/jdk-6u43-linux-x64.bin
```

I still cannot get the version to show in the list of possible versions when I run:

```
jeffrey@jeffrey-Satellite-M645:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There is only one alternative in link group java: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
jeffrey@jeffrey-Satellite-M645:~$
```

I have seen many posts on this site regarding this using specific tools or techniques that do not address my environment or the fact that I already have the binary file - I just need to install it and select it as default.

What am I not understanding?  How do I get the bin file installed so that I can make it the default version.

Comment: This was removed a few releases ago. You can go to java.com to find the latest version of the SDK for linux and install it manually.

Comment: Uninstall the Openjdk version first and then install the Oracle Java version.

Comment: @kibaltz - other posts recommend against uninstalling OpenJDK version because of dependency issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your java alternative is not installed (even if java program is installed).

You first need to run the following command :

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /path/to/bin/java 100
```

Then, you'll be able to execute `update-alternatives --config java` command.

Comment: It refers to your new java bin installation. (it should be something like `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_43/bin/java` in your case)